# Short circuit evaluation in JavaScript - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, operator-keyword, expression-evaluation

I would like to use short circuit evaluation syntax (with `&&` operator) as described by example in the [article](https://blog.usejournal.com/mastering-javascripts-and-logical-operators-fd619b905c8f):

Say, I have this situation:

```
function externalFunction() {

    id == ...
    text == ...

    // OK: Standard if syntax is fine

    if ( aFunction(id, text) ) return

    // KO: Short circuit evaluation generate a RUN-TIME ERROR: 
    // SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'
    // anotherFunction(id, text) && return
    //                              ^^^^^^

    anotherFunction(id, text) && return


}
```

Why I have the error?
Maybe I can't use a single statement with language keyword (`return`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right hand side of `&&` needs to be an *expression*. You're trying to put a statement there.

The `&&` has to evaluate as *something* but `return x` doesn't give you a *value*. It exits the function and passes its RHS to the calling function.

Comment: thanks, true. I was looking to find an "elegant"/short way to evaluate a list of functions/conditions, that have to return from the external function in case they return true.

Comment: Use an `if` statement. It is clear and elegant. Extreme brevity is not a virtue.